# Skip Specific Dupliframes?

Tags: rendering

I am using dupliframes to copy an object along a path but is there any way to skip a specific frames? They don’t repeat so I can’t use “On” and “Off.” And I can’t use the array and curve modifier because it distorts the mesh.

Comment: You could consider using the *animation nodes* addon. It is very easy to create the described sort of effect.

Comment: How could I use the animation node addon? Sorry I have never used it.

Comment: It is a node based system, which can procedurally generate [many things](https://i.imgur.com/cZGCWk2.png). It will however take you approx 2-10 hours to learn it.